# How to let PL/SQL know not to process this data again if the stored procedure is run

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I am running a PL/SQL script in oracle to load data from a cursor into a table. I thought of adding a column called 'Processed' to the cursor, and having the code check whether its been processed using that method next time the stored procedure is run; however, i am getting an error. What would be a better approach? I am trying to prevent duplicate entries in the event that i run the stored procedure multiple times. Below is my code:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Test_proc
IS
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT   SUM(v.value_tx)  AS sum_of_values ,
             e.entity_id      AS entity_id ,
             e.entity_name_tx AS entity_name ,
             e.ei_id_tx       AS ei_id ,
             v.create_dt      AS create_dt ,
             v.hr_num         AS hr_num ,
             v.utc_offset ,
             v.data_date ,
             v.hr_utc ,
             v.hr ,
             v.data_code ,
             'N' AS processed
    FROM     value v
    join     submission_value sv
    ON       v.value_id = sv.value_id
    join     form_field ff
    ON       sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
    join     submission s
    ON       sv.submission_id = s.submission_id
    join     survey_respondent sr
    ON       s.survey_respondent_id = s.survey_respondent_id
    join     entity e
    ON       sr.entity_id = e.entity_id
    WHERE    ei_id_tx IN ('ABC',
                          'AECD',
                          'AVA')
    AND      ff.form_field_id IN ('77421',
                                  '77471')
    GROUP BY e.entity_id,
             e.entity_name_tx,
             e.ei_id_tx,
             v.create_dt,
             v.hr_num,
             v.utc_offset,
             v.data_date,
             v.hr_utc,
             v.hr,
             v.data_code;

l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1
    INTO  l_var;

    EXIT
  WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    IF l_var.processed = 'n' THEN
      INSERT INTO value
                  (
                              energy_product_id,
                              data_source_id,
                              unit_cd,
                              value_tx,
                              utc_offset,
                              data_date,
                              hr_utc,
                              hr,
                              hr_num,
                              data_code,
                              create_dt,
                              create_user_id,
                              modify_dt,
                              modify_user_id,
                              effective_dt,
                              inactive_dt
                  )
                  VALUES
                  (
                              '333',
                              '747',
                              'NA',
                              l_var.sum_of_values,
                              l_var.utc_offset,
                              l_var.data_date,
                              l_var.hr_utc,
                              l_var.hr,
                              l_var.hr_num,
                              l_var.data_code,
                              SYSDATE,
                              '1',
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              NULL
                  );

      SET l_var.processed = 'n';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
END test_proc;
```

Thanks in advance and please let me know if there is anything further I need to add and/or clarify.

Comment: Add a dated entry to a separate log table, and check for its existence before you run the proc.

Comment: how would i do that? is there some sort of documentation online i can read regarding this? confused how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding *processed = N* to a cursor won't help much; actually, won't help at all. You'd need to update table you fetch data from, instead. For example,

```
update value set processed = 'Y'
  where id = l_var.value_table_id
```

and then remove those rows from cursor with

```
and value.processed <> 'Y'
```

Though, a more common option is to include yet another condition into the WHERE clause which won't take rows that have already been inserted. It can be done with `IN` or `EXISTS`. Something like this:

```
cursor c1 is select 
  ...
  where <your current conditions here>
    and not exists (select null from values
                    where <condition that joins VALUES table with one (or more)
                           tables from the FROM clause>
```

This "condition" is usually some ID, for example

```
where values.id = value.id
  and ...
```

Comment: confused, so would it be : ...not exists ( select null from values where values.id = value.id) . there is no 'Values' table. or did you  mean 'where value.id = value.id)

Comment: Sorry; it is the VALUE table, I misread your (previously unformatted) code. So, you SELECT from VALUE (and some other tables) and INSERT into VALUE again. In that case, I'm afraid that my second option (EXISTS) won't help. Perhaps you should consider altering the table, adding the PROCESSED column and update it so that you wouldn't select those values again.

Comment: my mistake, sorry about that. trying to get used to the interface. what i am ultimately trying to do is calculate/ aggregate some values in the value table and insert it back into the value table (if that makes sense)

Comment: It's OK, you'll get used to it :) Though, try to properly format code you write. No need to do it manually - if your GUI supports that feature, use it. Otherwise, have a look at Instant SQL Formatter, here: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm  It is not perfect, but it's better than none (i.e. unformatted code which is difficult to read).